# Execute Java Program From Java Code using Process

Tags: java

I am trying to execute a java code by using `Process` class.
Here is my code.

Class file which is trying to execute is.

```
class Demo{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}

class Pro {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("java Demo");
            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process process = builder.start();
            InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Both classes are in different file and in the same folder.

O/P

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java Demo": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at GFG.main(GFG.java:13)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 3 more
```

Comment: Probably java can not find "Demo". Consider giving it the full path.

Comment: i tried but getting same error.

Comment: Should be `new ProcessBuilder("java", "Demo")`. And it may help to give the full path to `java`.

Comment: Why do you need this? why not just import the class and run it as such? Java is compatible with Java, you know ..

Comment: @ErnestKiwele Thank you so much.
It got worked.

Comment: @Stultuske I am just working around Process class.
So, it is just random demo program.
To learn behavior of Process class.

Comment: Can u tell me, how to check whether a process is waiting for an I/O

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
    private static final String LOCATION = "D:\\test.java";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException,IOException{

        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);

        List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
        command.add("javac");  //or command.add("javac -jar")
        command.add(LOCATION);

        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        Map<String, String> environ = builder.environment();

        final Process process = builder.start();

        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        System.out.println("Program terminated!");
      }
    }
```

Hope this helps,

**Addendum (how to wait for process):**

```
private String executeCommand(String command) {

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = 
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                    String line = "";           
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

calling:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExecuteShellComand obj = new ExecuteShellComand();

    String domainName = "https://wwww.google.com";

    //in mac oxs
    String command = "ping -c 3 " + domainName;

    //in windows
    //String command = "ping -n 3 " + domainName;

    String output = obj.executeCommand(command);

    System.out.println(output);

}
```

This is an example to ping some page, 3 times and wait for response.

Comment: Can u tell me, how to check whether a process is waiting for an I/O

Comment: try Process.waitFor(), method blocks the current thread until your process is finished or the thread is interrupted.

Comment: For example my Demo class takes user input.
e.g.,
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

And that Demo class is executed as process from my Test class.
I don't have any way to check whether my Process is waiting for user input.

This problem is like online compilers.
Where if user doesn't provide any input then it throws some kind of error.

Comment: sorry i didn't get you

Comment: added simple example with p.waitFor(); where You ping page 3 times, look in answer above.